# Missing Values in a Dataset for Multiple Regression

Tags: statistics, linear-regression

I've seen countless projects and tutorials on Kaggle where authors use calculated mean values to replace missing values in a column. However, I am now reading the Multiple Regression. A Primer. book by Paul D. Allison in which the author writes this:

> [...] Even worse than pairwise deletion is replacement with means. In this method, the missing values are replaced with the mean value of the variable for those individuals without the missing data.

So, I am curious is replacement with means a legitimate way to deal with missing values or are there more common and preferrable ways to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Replacement with the mean might not be appropriate because the person’s data point be very far off from the mean of that covariate. A better approach would be to use the person’s other covariates to infer the missing value of their covariate. There are whole books and courses devoted to missing data, but if you want somewhere to start, I recommend looking at the Expectation Maximization algorithm, which iteratively infers the most likely values of missing data while fitting the model/maximizing the observed data log likelihood.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'll definitely use your advice to learn more about the Expectation Maximization algorithm, but for my immediate purposes would it be an OK short-term solution to use the mean values group by some other column.



For example, if I have missing values in the House Size (Sq. Ft.) column, would it be an OK solution to use the means grouped by the Number of Bedrooms and/or neighborhood in which the house is located?

Comment: @KonstantinVoronin yes, that would be reasonable. However, it might lead to some collinearity as house size and number of bedrooms would be correlated. But it is a reasonable solution

Comment: You can also look into knn-imputation, inferring the most likely missing values based on similarity to other covariates